# Finding Coefficient of Term in Expansion (Multinomial/Binomial)

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, number-theory

I'm working on a proof of something and in the proof I need to find the coefficient of $s^{27}$ in $(\frac{1}{6}(s+s^{2}+s^{3}+s^{4}+s^{5}+s^{6}))^{10}$. Wolfram Alpha gives the answer to be: [image]

I believe this is the correct answer, however, in my proof I don't want to say by Wolfram Alpha, the coefficient of $s^{27}$ in $(\frac{1}{6}(s+s^{2}+s^{3}+s^{4}+s^{5}+s^{6}))^{10}$ is $\frac{2665}{104976}$. I think it is better that I solve for the coefficient of $s^{27}$ analytically or by hand. I wasn't sure, however what the best method to do this was. I was thinking maybe multinomial theorem (not binomial theorem since there are 6 terms)). However, there are many ways to combine powers of $s, s^2, s^3, s^4, s^5, \mbox{ and } s^6$ to get $s^{27}$. Thus, I don't know the best way to find the coefficient of $s^{27}$ by hand or analytically. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the easiest thing to do is simply say that the answer is $\frac{2665}{104976}$. But if you really want to do it by hand then this will work:

\begin{align}
 [s^{27}](s + s^2 + s^3 + s^4 + s^5 + s^6)^{10} &= [s^{17}](1 + s + s^2 + s^3 + s^4 + s^5)^{10} \\
&= [s^{17}]\frac{(1-s^6)^{10}}{(1-s)^{10}} \\
&= [s^{17}]\frac{1 - 10s^6 + 45s^{12}}{(1-s)^{10}} \\
&= [s^{17}]\frac{1}{(1-s)^{10}} - 10[s^{11}]\frac{1}{(1-s)^{10}} + 45[s^5]\frac{1}{(1-s)^{10}} \\
&= \binom{17 + 9}{9} - 10\binom{11 + 9}{9} + 45 \binom{5 + 9}{9} \\
&= 1535040.
\end{align}

So the coefficient you are looking for is
$$ \frac{1535040}{6^{10}} = \frac{2665}{104976}. $$

Comment: Hi @Trevor Gunn, thanks. I am a bit confused by the step how $(1-s^6)^{10}$ becomes $1-10s^6+45s^{12}$, how did you get this?

Comment: @kemb Binomial expansion. Those coefficients are 10 choose 1 and 10 choose 2. You don't need the higher terms because they don't affect the coefficient of $s^{17}$.

Comment: Thanks, can i ask several more questions, since I'm having a lot of trouble following. why then after this step do you say that this is equivalent to find the coefficient of $s^{11}$ and $s^5$. Also I don't understand the last step, how did you get (17 +9 choose 9), (11+9 choose 9), (5+9 choose 9) etc..

Comment: The coefficient of $s^{17}$ in $s^6f(s)$ is the same as the coefficient of $s^{11}$ in $f(s)$ for example. It is well known that $$ \frac{1}{(1 - s)^{k + 1}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n + k}{k} s^n. $$

Comment: I see thanks for the help.